# Full Text Search result similar to Mysql Like '%%' query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, sql-like

We are looking for mysql query which provide result exactly `like '%%'` query but using full text search `MATCH AGAINST`

For example

```
Select id,name from table where jobtitle like '%java software engineer in google%'
```

It gives all rows which contain line java software engineer in google

But if we use following mysql query then it gives a different result

```
Select id,name from table
where MATCH(jobtitle) AGAINST ('+java software engineer in google' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It gives rows which contain any word of from java software engineer in google

I want the exact output which comes from using like '%java software engineer in google%' query.

Answer (score 0):

As MySQL documentation on [Boolean fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) indicates (bolding is mine):

> The boolean full-text search capability supports the following
>   operators:  [...]
>
> "
>
> A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (“"”) characters matches
>   only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The
>   full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in
>   the FULLTEXT index for the words. **Nonword characters need not be
>   matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain
>   exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For
>   example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".**
>
> **If the phrase contains no words that are in the index, the result is
>   empty. The words might not be in the index because of a combination of
>   factors: if they do not exist in the text, are stopwords, or are
>   shorter than the minimum length of indexed words.**

So, use the `"` operator:

```
Select id,name from table
where MATCH(jobtitle) AGAINST ('"java software engineer in google"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The bolded section contains the caveat: the results may be slightly different because of the nature of the fulltext index.

Comment: your query show no result. no rows found and even row is there which contain exact line java software engineer in google. the line in database is jobs for java software engineer in google delhi

Comment: The word `in` is probably shorter than the minimum word length, therefore the fulltext index cannot find it, hence it does not return any records. See updated answer. The added part was the next paragraph in the linked MySQL manual...

Comment: ido not understand. i want match query to search this line java software engineer in google anywhere come in rows

Comment: Fulltext index does not index all words. It does not index words below certain length, nor words in its stopword list. These settings are there to limit the size of the fulltext index. Obviously, you may choose to overwrite them. Pls refer to MySQL manual on fine tuning fulltext indexes for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: basicly i want to search whole sentense anywhere in jobtitle so i use like '%%' but it increase too much load on mysql. so what i can do

Comment: I thought I gave you the answer for that: you can try to reduce the min word length and review your stop word list, and rebuild your fulltext index. However, you may still expect differences, since fulltext search searches for words, not the exact string representation. You may also try to eliminate words shorter than the min word length and prefix all words with the `+` operator. This way the top match will probably be the closest to the original search expression. Alternatively, you go for a different text search provider for MySQL, such a sphinx.